# Sit FrameLayout on top of WebView?

Tags: java, android, view, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

First off, I have read some of the other WebView questions and none of them appear to be having quite the same problem.

I've got a `WebView` and a `FrameLayout` , the FrameLayOut looks something like..

```
 FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
 EditText qbox = new EditText(this);
 box.setText(query);
 Button button = new Button(this);
 fl.addView(button, 45,45);
 fl.addView(box,275,45);
```

I then add the `Webview` and `FrameLayout` to my `LinearLayout` like so..

```
     LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
     webview.loadUrl(url);
     ll.addView(fl,300,45);
     ll.addView(webview, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

However, this renders weirdly.. rather than the FrameLayout displaying "on top of" the Webview it renders at the top of the page, with the webview to the right (mostly off page) and the rest of the screen black. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is horizontal by default. If you want the `LinearLayout` to be vertical, use `setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)`.